# Insert trigger issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, auditing

I am using a simple trigger `ins_process` for capturing inserts/updates on a table `process`. This `ins_process` inserts data into a table `process_audit`.

`process` has the following data originally inserted, in that order:

```
id    name    description
---   ----    -----------
1     proc1   sql
2     proc2   scripting
3     proc3   java
```

This creates the data in `process_audit` as follows:

```
id    name    description    insert_dt
---   ----    -----------    ---------
3     proc3   java           [a minute ago]
2     proc2   scripting      [a minute ago]
1     proc1   sql            [a minute ago]
```

Why do the records get inserted in the reverse order?. When I edit a row from the front-end, the data in `process_audit` is as follows:

```
id    name    description    insert_dt
---   ----    -----------    ---------
3     proc3   java           [a minute ago]
2     proc2   scripting      [a minute ago]
1     proc1   sql            [a minute ago]
2     proc2   scripting      [now]
```

This is not so much of a problem for me. I am wondering if this is a standard behaviour or if there is something wrong in the way I have created the trigger.

Here is how I created the trigger:

```
create trigger [dbo].[ins_process]  
on [dbo].[process] for insert, update    
as
set nocount on    
begin    
insert into process_audit
    (id, name, description, insertdate)    
select 
    id, name, description,current_timestamp
from inserted ins    
end
```

Also, the `id` column in table `process_audit` is not an Identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know in which order SQL inserted rows to the table?

I assume you query `select * from process_audit` and expect to see rows in the same order as they were inserted. This is not a valid expectation.

SQL server does not guarantee any order if `order by` is not specified.
Also, SQL server does not maintain the order of rows insertion.

Likely the returned results will be order by clustered index order, but still not guaranteed.

If you add own identity `Id` column or `CreatedDateTime` column with default constraint, this will be a better indicator of the insertion order.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the suggested method for getting the insertion order as I need it.